# What is the name of the track Rimmer is listening to in Red Dwarf IX when the others are in the diving bell being attacked by the despair squid?

Tags: red-dwarf

Rimmer listens to some questionable music but we shan't hold it against him. While watching Red Dwarf IX, I laughed when he was chair-dancing and not watching the monitors while the others were fending off the despair squid in the diving bell.

Is the track something the programme creators made themselves or commissioned specifically for Red Dwarf IX? Is it a track available commercially and if so, where?

Comment: Is the scene available on YouTube or other video service? My Red Dwarf DVDs were borrowed and never returned :(

Comment: “we shan't hold it against him” — yes we shall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Getting to Know You / I Whistle a Happy Tune* - [Ray Conniff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Conniff)

The [official episode guide](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/guide/index.cfm?seriesID=9&sectionID=library-music) identifies the piece:

> *Getting to Know You / I Whistle a Happy Tune* by Ray Coniff *[sic]*, played by Rimmer in the diving bell control room.

The song itself is a medley of [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_to_Know_You_(song)) [songs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Whistle_a_Happy_Tune) from the 1951 musical [*The King and I*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_and_I), but Conniff's arrangement dates to [at least](http://www.rayconniff.info/comcast/original/albums/broadwayrhythm.html) 1958; I couldn't tell you how easy it would be to find either version commercially. However, there are several uploads on YouTube for your listening pleasure; for example: